# Is this correct that I would have to modify all the code that uses arrow functions in order to test them?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spectator

My background with unit testing is minimal.

From what I've found on Google it appears that I would have to change a lot of the code in our application in order to unit test arrow function code.

So, if code were as follow

```
 class MyComponent {
   fun: () => 'hello';
   constructor() {};
 }
```

Then I must change it to something like the following in order to unit test it.

**Create an interface**

```
Interface MyService {
  fun: () => string;
}
```

**And change the code,**

```
class Component {
   constructor() {
     this.mysService = () => {
       return {
         fun: () => 'hello'
       };
     };
   }
   myService: () => MyService;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change anything in your code in order to test your arrow functions:

Assuming you have this component with the `myFunc` arrow function:

```
export class TestcomponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  myfunc = () => 'hello';

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

in your spec file, you can do the following:

```
describe('TestcomponentComponent', () => {
  let component: TestcomponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestcomponentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestcomponentComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestcomponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('myFunc should return "hello"', () => {
    expect(component.myfunc()).toBe('hello');
  })
});
```